# How to pass this line in docker file. [/runjd.sh installjdk -Dname=javaversion]

Tags: docker, dockerfile

when i am using the CMD parameter, docker build is success.
But To run the docker container, container is existing immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read about docker & how it works after container is started.

More about how to read logs of container: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

Comment: How to write the docker file this line.  ./runjd.sh  installjava  -DNAME=java